# Meaning of Porte qui claque?

Tags: grammaire, expressions

*Porte* means door, *qui* means who and *claque* means slap.

How does this mean Slamming door?

I am not able to understand the usage of **qui** here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say for instance "Il y a une porte qui claque au premier étage." you mean that on the first floor a door is more or less regularly but constantly being banged against its door jamb by a draught. You use the same construction for other things, in particular windows and shutters, that are subjected to this action of the wind or of draughts.

- Il y avait des volets qui claquaient dans la rue et personne ne pensait à les arrimer au murs par les attaches prévues à cet effet.

There is an important matter of context  which makes the difference between the meaning given to the verb in what precedes and a meaning very similar. That meaning of the verb is "to bang against something once or to close with a bang". It might be difficult to make out which is which.

- Elle se déplaçait maintenant dans la maison, passant d'étage en étage et ouvrant une chambre ou une salle de bain quand une porte claqua à l'étage supérieur. (*Here a door banged once or got shut with a bang.*)
- La porte a claqué, je l'ai entendue, il faut aller voir. (*banged, got shut*)
- La porte a claqué pendant un moment au rythme des coups de vents jusqu'à ce qu'il se lève et aille la fermer. (*banged repeatedly*)

Answer (score 4):

The OP is asking about the usage of **qui**, qui is a relative pronoun (un pronom relatif) that replaces the word preceding it (l'antécédent) and *usually* acts as a subject. The sentence after *qui* is a *subordonnée relative complément de l'antécédent* meaning it complements that word. An English analogy would be **who**, this is the guy who loves you, *who* is replacing the guy here in the same way that *qui* replaced the door.

Comment: +1 for addressing *qui*. Just my opinion but in light of OP's "qui means who," maybe you could add that *qui* can also mean *that/which* and give an example using one of those two (eg, "This is the door that I slammed in your face").

Comment: Thanks, but in your example *that* would be translated to **que** and not qui, c'est la porte que j'ai claquée dans ta face

Comment: It seems to me suggesting *that* is still relevant, e.g.: *La porte **qui** fait du bruit* → The door **that** makes noise.

Comment: Although this answer is probably correct, I feel like if the OP understood all the technical words in the answer then he would already have enough knowledge to understand the French translation without needing to ask the question.